# Request Animation Frame Javascript Game Timer

Tags: javascript, timer

The following works:

```
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
return  window.requestAnimationFrame ||
window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame   ||
window.mozRequestAnimationFrame      ||
window.oRequestAnimationFrame        ||
window.msRequestAnimationFrame       ||
function(callback){ window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60); };
})();

function gameLoop() {
    requestAnimFrame(gameLoop);
}
```

However, when I try to package the functionality using the Module Pattern, as such:

```
var GameModule = {

    requestAnimFrame: function() { 
    return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame  ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame     ||
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame       ||
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame      ||
    function(callback){ window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60); };
   },

   gameLoop: function() {
       this.requestAnimFrame(this.gameLoop);
   }
};

// run the game
(function(){
    Game.gameLoop();
})();
```

...it only calls requestAnimFrame once. I've been messing around with it for a long time and can't seem to figure out a way to have it operate recursively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed:

```
this.requestAnimFrame(this.gameLoop());
```